Adding scroll navigation
a flutter app problem, app not running showing this error.
the error
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/helpers-      1.2.3/lib/helpers/misc_build/build_color.dart:88:47: Error: The getter 'selectedRowColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'selectedRowColor'.
  Color get selectedRow => Theme.of(_context).selectedRowColor;
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application. 

the code:
import 'package:afro_chat/screens/chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:afro_chat/screens/update_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll_navigation/scroll_navigation.dart';
//import 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart';

class SummaryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'summary_screen';

  @override
  State<SummaryScreen> createState() => _SummaryScreenState();
}

class _SummaryScreenState extends State<SummaryScreen> {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // theme: ThemeData(
      //   colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      //   selectedRowColor: Colors.blue,
      // ),
      home: MySummaryPage(),
    );
  }
}


class MySummaryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Mr UAM'),
      ),
      body: TitleScrollNavigation(
        barStyle: TitleNavigationBarStyle(
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
          spaceBetween: 40,
        ),
        titles: [
          "Summaries",
          "Updates",
          "Chat",
        ],
        pages: [
          SummaryScreen(), 
          UpdateScreen(), 
          ChatScreen(), 
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I'm using a package from pub.dev :scroll_navigation: ^1.3.2, with code:
return TitleScrollNavigation(
    barStyle: TitleNavigationBarStyle(
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
      spaceBetween: 40,
    ),
    titles: [
      "Main Page",
      "Personal Information",
      "Personalization",
      "Security",
      "Payment Methods",
    ],
    pages: [
      Container (color: Colors.blue[50]),
      Container (color: Colors.red[50]),
      Container (color: Colors.green[50]),
      Container (color: Colors.purple[50]),
      Container (color: Colors.yellow[50]),
    ],
);

I wanted to navigate between three screens, example [package demo] (https://i.sstatic.net/CZ8HUBrk.png).
Not sure what's wrong, code shows no error in android studio until when run.
